How is vertical slice architecture structured with Dapper without using MediatoR?
I'm trying to migrate to a VSA architecture so that I no longer have grouping by layer but by feature.
Here's the architecture I ended up with :
-API 
       - Database  (My access layer ConnectionString...)
          - IDatabaseAccess1 
          - IDatabaseAccess2
       - Features
          - Products
             - CreateProduct
                - CreateProductController
                - CreateProductService
                - CreateProductRepository
                - CreateProduct (My DTO) 
             - GetProduct
                - GetProductController
                - GetProductService
                - GetProductRepository
                - GetProduct

After looking at and analyzing some repositories, I realize the difference between this structure and the one proposed by others.
I often see the use of mediator and minimal API as well as grouping in an endpoint.
(For my part, I use a Dapper micro ORM and therefore repositories on top of it, and the fact of grouping everything in a class doesn't appeal to me).

Should I use Mediator? I don't seem to need it at the moment, or am I missing something?

In terms of structure, would it be a good idea to create my interfaces in my classes to avoid duplicating the number of files? "CreateProductService / ICreateProductService for testing purpose)

Do you have any criticisms?


